# Check which elements of an array belong to a collection without using loop?

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection of 10000 items in MongoDB. The front end user submits an array of 100 items, and wants to know which of the 100 items belong to my collection.

Can I query it without using a loop?

Thanks!

----update: "more details" requested by comment:----

Sure, let's suppose my collection is about books (_id, book title, author name). Front end user submits an array of book titles. I need to answer which of the titles can be found in the db.

Also, suppose the book titles are always unique on both ends.

Comment: Are they "distinct" items? Where the array testing and the collection never have the same value more than once? You also need to be clear on "item". This could simply mean a "number" or it could mean a more complex "object". Both have different considerations. Good questions provide a "small" example of what is submitted, stored and the expected result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can just use the $in operator which expects an array with titles of books and it should return the objects which contain the same.

```
db.getCollection('book').find({ title: { $in: ["string1", "string2"] }})
```

Comment: Oh my god I never thought it was so simple. I thought in order to use $in on a field, the field must contain an array.

Comment: I feel so stupid now. But considering this question took 2 hours to receive a single answer, it must have deceived many people.